# Telegram-Bot does not respond correctly

Tags: python, logging, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I am doing a telegram bot, I have a merger that is to divide that does not work but to add if it does, does anyone know why?

```
import logging

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Hola!')


def help(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Help!')

def sumar(update, context):
    try:
        numero1 = int(context.args[0])
        numero2 = int(context.args[1])

        suma = numero1 + numero2
        update.message.reply_text('La suma es '+str(suma))

    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        update.message.reply_text('Por favor utiliza dos numeros')    

def dividir(update, context):
    try:
        numero1 = int(context.args[0])
        numero2 = int(context.args[1])

        div= numero1 / numero2
        update.message.reply_text('La division da '+str(div))

    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        update.message.reply_text('Por favor utiliza dos numeros')

def echo(update, context):
    """Echo the user message."""
    update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)


def error(update, context):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)


def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    # Make sure to set use_context=True to use the new context based callbacks
    # Post version 12 this will no longer be necessary
    updater = Updater("1225696978:AAFsJYex51HMRbKL814tLJJPczJMu3nLlYY", use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    botm3 = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Sumar", sumar))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Division", dividir))

    # on noncommand i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    botm3.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo))

    # log all errors
    botm3.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have two functions for the bot, one works the other does not and they are the same structure but it does not take effect.
I leave you my token so you can do the tests if you want the name of the bot is:
@ moha_m03_1bot

Comment: def sumar = add like 5 + 5

Comment: dividr = divide like 100 / 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the name of the command is confusing:

- '/Sumar 2 2' -> La suma es 4
- '/Division 4 2' -> La division da 2.0
- '/Dividir 2 2' -> doesnt match any command

The commands are called `Sumar` and `Division`, maybe you meant them to be called `Sumar` and `Dividir`

Answer (score 1):

it is 'division' not 'dividir' don't try the function name in telegram try 'division'

```
botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Division", dividir))
```

It is working perfectly for me

Comment: Not for me. and know why